# emit IL for basic arithmetic ops

Tags: .net, cil, reflection.emit, il

I'm fairly new to C#, and have recently learned that it's possible to emit IL to implement a simple evaluation stack:

```
stack [ B C * A + ] ==> push B, push C, DO MULT, push A, DO ADD, POP return value

this example arises from the string "A + ( B  * C )"
```

Can someone provide some advice and/or a sample IL snippet of the basic operation - i.e. push 1,2 or 3 doubles and invoke an unary, binary or ternary function or arithmetic operator on them.

Your advice may include whether or not emitting IL is a good idea.  The expressions are assumptions fed to a monte-carlo simulation - so there is a good reason to think about speeding them up, but I don't want to do this if it's regarded as doable but unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exczf7b9.aspx for an excellent description of how to do this.  Extremely well commented & well written.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing the parsing anyway to extract the operands and operators in your expressions, why don't you just call specific functions to perform the various operations? It'd be significantly simpler than emitting & compiling IL on the fly. With your example, you could do this:

```
MyStack<object> m_oStack = new MyStack<object> ();

double Add () // takes 2 params from stack
{
    return ( m_oStack.Pop () + m_oStack.Pop () );
}

double Multiply () // takes 2 params from stack
{
    return ( m_oStack.Pop () * m_oStack.Pop () );
}

// during evaluating the expression:
... // parse

m_oStack.Push ( fB );

... // parse

m_oStack.Push ( fC );

... // parse

m_oStack.Push ( Multiply () );

... // parse

m_oParamStack.Push ( fA );

... // parse

m_oParamStack.Push ( Add () );

// you're done with evaluating the expression, the result is
// on top of the stack
```

So as you're evaluating the various parts of your expression, you just keep values in a stack and call your own functions as you parse the various sub-expressions.

This is all doable by emitting IL but it's going to be significantly more complicated, since you still need to do all the parsing, managing all the input parameters, etc., but on top of all that, you also have to emit IL and then execute it on the fly.

Comment: The parsing gets done once, but the evaluation gets done a million times (as above) - so the idea was to boost the speed of the eval routine from pseudo-code speed to JIT speed (unless, as you suggest, it's too hairy).